# Batch Script to overwrite a file with first 5 lines

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with x lines and I would like to overwrite that file with only first 5 lines deleting the rest. I need to do this with a batch script. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 3):

As long as each of first 5 lines is <= 1021 bytes long, and there are no control characters at the end of any of the 5 lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
<"test.txt" >"test.txt.new" (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 5) do (
    set "ln="
    set /p "ln="
    echo(!ln!
  )
)
move /y "test.txt.new" "test.txt" >nul
```

Or you could use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward. This solution works well with any size file as long as no line exceeds 2 gigabytes - effectively no limitation.

JREPL.BAT is really designed to do regular expression search and replace on text files, but it is convenient to use it to get the head or tail of a file.

```
jrepl "^" "" /jbegln "quit=(ln>=5)" /f test.txt /o -
```

Comment: EDIT - Oops, I forgot the critical `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: EDIT - Added JREPL.BAT solution

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set "file_to_process=E:\somefile.txt"

set "first_n_lines=5"

break>"%temp%\empty"&&fc "%temp%\empty" "%file_to_process%" /lb  %first_n_lines% /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" >5.txt


rem move /y 5.txt "%file_to_process%"
```

remove the `rem` on the last line if `5.txt` file is what you want.

Comment: Ooh - I don't recall ever seeing this before. Of course it fails if any line of source is `*****`, and MORE corrupts tab characters. But I like this hack!

Comment: @dbenham - 10x. This can be put in `FOR /F` with "skip=4" to avoid `more` , but this will make the code more verbose (and I like in this most that it's almost convenient one-liner).

Comment: The FOR /F will also slow things down, especially if you want to preserve empty lines. I like your posted answer because it is fast and concise. I just wanted to point out the minor limitations.